# If I were to buy a game digitally on eShop for the Nintendo switch, could I play that game on another Nintendo switch?

Tags: nintendo-switch

Can anyone tell me if I were to buy a game virtually for the Nintendo switch, and my switch breaks,and then I buy a new one, could I play that game on my new console?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can download and play the game on any Nintendo Switch console.  The account that purchased it would, however be the only account able to play the game if not installed on the account holder's "Primary Console." You have to switch(pun intended) your "Primary Console" to your new console.